# McLaurin series expansion to evaluate a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I have a maths assignment due for college based on the McLaurin series and don't understand how to do it. I need to use a McLaurin series expansion to evaluate a function.  The function is the solution this differential equation: 
$$
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} + 5\frac{df}{dx} + 4f = 0, 
$$
with $df/dx(0) = 0$ and $f(0) = 2$
Can you please help me make a start with this and I will get back to you with any progress I make.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$

You have:
$$f(0)=2$$
$$f'(0)=0$$

Replacing that in your differential equation:

$$
f''(0) + 5f'(0) + 4f(0) = 0 
$$
$$
f''(0)+5\cdot 0 +4\cdot 2=0
$$

$$
f''(0)=-8
$$

If you take the derivative of your differential equation:

$$
\frac{d^3f}{dx^3} + 5\frac{df^2}{dx^2} + 4\frac{df}{dx} = 0, 
$$

And evaluating in $0$:

$$
\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}(0) + 5f''(0) + 4f'(0) = 0, 
$$
$$
\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}(0)=40
$$

In general you can derivate $n$ times to obtain:

$$f^{(n+2)}+5f^{(n+1)}+4f^{(n)}=0$$

Which can be evaluated in $0$ to obtain a relationship between the derivatives at $x=0$:

$$f^{(n+2)}(0)+5f^{(n+1)}(0)+4f^{(n)}(0)=0$$

**Method 2:**

Call

$$a_n=f^{(n)}(0)$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^{n}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!} x^{n}$$
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n-2)!} x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n+2}}{n!} x^{n}$$

Replacing in the differential equation:

$$
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} + 5\frac{df}{dx} + 4f = 0, 
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_{n+2}+5a_{n+1}+4a_{n}) x^n=0
$$

Therefore you have the recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+2}+5a_{n+1}+4a_{n}=0$$
$$a_{0}=2$$
$$a_{1}=0$$

**Note:** if you are not able to solve the relationship between the coefficients just show a few terms. The recurrence solution is (using wolfram alpha I'm not an expert on this):

$$f^{(n)}(0) = -\frac{2}{3} (-1)^n (4^n-4)$$

Comment: Using Method 1 would I be correct in saying that the next step would be f′′′′(0) + 5f′′′(0) + 4f′′(0) = 0  giving f′′′′(0) + 5.40 + 4.-8 = 0  which gives f′′′′(0) = -168 ?

Comment: @user202149 yes it's correct

Comment: Thanks so much for your help rlartiga, much appreciated.  Does the process just continue in this fashion and if so, how far do I need to keep going?  Also, could you give an example of what happens if you put in a particular value for the argument x?  Do you just place it in each part of the series formula for x, x^2 and so on?  And then multiply it by the derivative value/factorial value?

Comment: yes, you just replace. The ideal is solve the recurrence relation (i.e. find the pattern of the coefficients)

Comment: One last thing, is f′(0) always equal to 0 and f(0) always equal to 2 and what's their relevance in the expansion i.e. why choose those 2 values, can different values be used?

Comment: The problem have that initial values could be perfectly others

Comment: So they just happen to be 0 and 2 in this case i.e. for this particular differential equation? And again, how far do I need to go with the derivation to answer the question correctly? Also, do I NEED to solve the recurrence relation? (I don't understand this part)

Comment: @user202149 See my edit I hope it could help you.

Comment: rlartiga, many thanks for your time and effort.  I don't fully understand the coefficient relationship/recurrence solution but, would I be right in saying that if you were on the 10th derivative (for example) you would just substitute the value 10 for n in the formulas you mentioned? Also, the recurrence solution shows the relationship between the coefficients, is that correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: Brilliant! So I'm good to go with this now?

Comment: yes, you are ready

Comment: Thank you so much rlartiga you've really helped me out here : D